# Why ehcache deadlock?

Tags: spring, tomcat, cluster-computing, deadlock, ehcache

One of our projects use the cluster of spring 3.2 plus tomcat 7.0, and use ehcache2.8.0 for better performance, also we use RMI for replication like http://ehcache.org/documentation/replication/rmi-replicated-caching. Config like:

```
<bean id="method-cache-key-generator" class="com.services.cache.MethodCacheKeyGenerator" />
<bean id="service-cache-manager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="ehcache-manager" />
</bean>
<bean id="ehcache-manager"
        class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" />
```

and:

```
<cache:advice id="user-service-read-cache-advice"
      cache-manager="service-cache-manager" key-generator="method-cache-key-generator">
  <cache:caching cache="userCache">
      <cache:cacheable method="get*" />
      <cache:cacheable method="find*" />
  </cache:caching>
</cache:advice>
<cache:advice id="user-service-write-cache-advice"
      cache-manager="service-cache-manager" key-generator="method-cache-key-generator">
  <cache:caching cache="userCache">
    <cache:cache-evict method="create*" all-entries="true" />
    <cache:cache-evict method="update*" all-entries="true" />
    <cache:cache-evict method="remove*" all-entries="true" />
    <cache:cache-evict method="reset*" all-entries="true" />
    <cache:cache-evict method="change*" all-entries="true" />
  </cache:caching>
</cache:advice>

<bean id="cached-user-info-service" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
  <property name="target" ref="original-user-info-service" />
  <property name="interceptorNames">
    <list>
      <value>user-service-clone-advice</value>
      <value>user-service-read-cache-advice</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
<bean id="cached-user-service" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
  <property name="target" ref="original-user-service" />
    <property name="interceptorNames">
    <list>
      <value>user-service-write-cache-advice</value>
    </list>
      </property>
</bean>
```

We found that end-users cannot log on after using the system for a short time, the tomcat has to be restarted to solve the problem. However, we can’t reproduce this problem by our testers on the very same system servers. 
We use jconsole to check the servers and find that a large amount of threads are waiting for a thread lock, and this thread deadlock on ehcache.

part of stack is:

```
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
net.sf.ehcache.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node.tryAwaitLock(ConcurrentHashMap.java:687)
net.sf.ehcache.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.internalClear(ConcurrentHashMap.java:2016)
net.sf.ehcache.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.clear(ConcurrentHashMap.java:2680)
net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.OnHeapCachingTier.clear(OnHeapCachingTier.java:213)
net.sf.ehcache.store.CacheStore.removeAll(CacheStore.java:250)
net.sf.ehcache.Cache.removeAll(Cache.java:2451)
net.sf.ehcache.Cache.removeAll(Cache.java:2436)
org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCache.clear(EhCacheCache.java:74)
org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.inspectCacheEvicts(CacheAspectSupport.java:243)
org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.inspectAfterCacheEvicts(CacheAspectSupport.java:227)
org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:212)
org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:66)
```

For some reasons, we cannot ask our end-users to help us reproduce this bug. My question is under what kind of conditions ehcache will not release the write lock?
 Any suggestions for us to find the method to solve this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: Ehcache should never not release a lock... now, are you seeing an instance of that, or is another thread holding that lock, while trying to acquire another one, ... or something?

Comment: Also, looking at the spring config there, do I read this right that any of these methods matched there should "evict all entries" of userCache? If that's the case that seems suspicious to me... Basically wonder how much it actually is deadlocked vs. spending much time concurrently clearing things out. Doing a thread dump should show any actual dead lock btw (i.e. involve more than 1 thread!)

Comment: @alex, Thanks a lot for your replies. Personally, I really do not agree the method of “evict all entries”, but I think it may not the reason cause this deadlock. 
System Servers has been restarted and I can’t reproduce this bug or do thread dump now. But when this deadlock appeared before, I used JConsole to check the servers and found that all threads were waiting for one thread(by thread status), and this very thread was hanging on the method of “tryAwaitLock”(with no relationships of other threads). This condition makes me really confuse.

Comment: I can only check codes and configuration files atm. I wonder if there are some other ways to find out why this deadlock appeared. I will be very grateful for your help.

Comment: Posting the entire thread dump would be really helpful ... Hard to tell anything w/o that.